# how to distinct only one column in the foreach laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

first, sorry for my not good english, I've done a query with so many joins that it produces very complex output,

this my **controller**

```
$detail_plotting = Detail_Plotting::select('detail_plotting.*', 'user.NAMA_USER','plotting.ID_PLOTTING','unit_kerja_prodi_homebase.STATUS_UNIT','unit_kerja_prodi_homebase.NAMA_UNIT','unit_kerja_prodi_homebase.ID_UNIT','departemen.ID_DEPARTEMEN','periode.ID_PERIODE','mata_kuliah.KODE_MK','mata_kuliah.NAMA_MK','mata_kuliah.SKS','mata_kuliah.SEMESTE')
                            ->join('user', 'user.ID_USER', '=', 'detail_plotting.ID_USER')
                            ->join('unit_kerja_prodi_homebase', 'unit_kerja_prodi_homebase.ID_UNIT', '=', 'user.ID_UNIT')
                            ->join('departemen', 'departemen.ID_DEPARTEMEN', '=', 'unit_kerja_prodi_homebase.ID_DEPARTEMEN')
                            ->join('plotting', 'plotting.ID_PLOTTING', '=', 'detail_plotting.ID_PLOTTING')
                            ->join('periode', 'periode.ID_PERIODE', '=', 'plotting.ID_PERIODE')
                            ->join('detail_mk', 'detail_mk.ID_DETAIL_MK', '=', 'plotting.ID_DETAIL_MK')
                            ->join('mata_kuliah', 'detail_mk.KODE_MK', '=', 'mata_kuliah.KODE_MK')
                            ->where('mata_kuliah.STATUS_MK',1)
                            ->where('detail_mk.STATUS_DETAIL_MK',1)
                            ->where('unit_kerja_prodi_homebase.STATUS_UNIT',1)
                            ->where('unit_kerja_prodi_homebase.ID_DEPARTEMEN',Session::get('departemen'))
                            // ->where('user.ID_ROLE',2)
                            ->where('periode.STATUS_PERIODE',1)
                            // ->latest('detail_plotting.ID_DETAIL_PLOTTING')
                            ->orderBy('user.NAMA_USER','asc')
                            ->get();
        // $mk = MataKuliah::where('STATUS_MK',1)->get();
        return view('beban-dosen-prodi.beban-dosen-prodi-index',compact('detail_plotting'));
```

next i have built view in laravel blade file like this

**blade view**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>No</th>
                      <th>Dosen</th>
                      <th>Kode MK</th>
                      <th>MK</th>
                      <th>SKS</th>
                      <th>Semester</th>
                      <th>Prodi</th>
                      <th>Beban</th>
                      <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <?php $counter=1;?>
                  @forelse($detail_plotting as $detail_plottings)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $counter }}</td>
                        <?php $counter++;?>
                        <td>{{ $detail_plottings->NAMA_USER }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $detail_plottings->KODE_MK }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $detail_plottings->NAMA_MK }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $detail_plottings->SKS }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $detail_plottings->SEMESTE }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $detail_plottings->NAMA_UNIT }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $detail_plottings->BEBAN_SKS }}</td>
                        <td>Total</td>
                      </tr>
                    @empty
                    @endforelse
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

The query I did was successful and produces an output like the image below

[image]

I've been reading and looking for some ways, such as `unique()` or `groupBy()` but the outputs are not correct because they only show 2 data

my question, how to design or other way to make it like distinct() only for second column only

Comment: I understand 50%, will you be more clear about your question like you want to do?

Comment: try ->groupBy('user.NAMA_USER')->get();

Comment: @Hamelraj I've tried using groupBy('user.NAME_USER')->get() but the resulting output is only 2

Comment: @MiteshRathod i have a rough image of the output i want like this https://imgur.com/a/Zsz9ajk

Comment: this my output after using `groupBy` https://imgur.com/a/fdVtDfo

Comment: why not create a view and then query to that view like a normal query ?

Comment: seems you have two user so you will get two raw data. seems you doesn't know groupby.

Answer (score 0):

Add `->groupBy('user.NAMA_USER')` to your query.

But it will work only if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode is disabled in MySQL.

Comment: I've tried using groupBy('user.NAME_USER')->get() but the resulting output is only 2 :"(

Comment: On your screenshot there are only 2 distinct users, so 2 records is a correct output.